# angularjs post request to nodejs api

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I've angularjs post call (submit a login form data) to a /login nodejs API endpoint. The data received at Nodejs endpoint (in request.body) is not in json format but it has extra padding as shown below,
{ '{"email": "a@b.com", "password": "aaa"}': ''}
What is this format? How do I access 'email' and/or password from this object?

Client code,

```
login: function(loginData, callback) {
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/login',
    data: loginData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www.form-urlencoded'}
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
    });
}
```

Server code:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Email:' + req.body.email);  //this gives undefined error
  console.log(req.body);   // shows { '{"email": "a@b.com", "password": "aaa"}': ''}
}
```

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

--Atarangp

Comment: You have a stringified object in your body - `JSON.parse(req.body)`

Comment: JSON.parse() gives internal server error with 'Unexpected token o' error in Object.parse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default angularjs use JSON.stringify. If you wanna use x-www-form-urlencoded, you have to specify your transform function.

```
// transforme obj = {attr1: val1} to "attr1=" + encodeURIComponent(val1) + "&attr2=" ... 
function transformRequestToUrlEncoded(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj)
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    return str.join("&");
  }

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: your_url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    transformRequest: transformRequestToUrlEncoded, // specify the transforme function
    data: datas
  });
```